# Where is HexDump in the Android API?

Tags: java, android, usbserial, hexdump

I'm using this [library](https://github.com/mik3y/usb-serial-for-android) to read from and write to USB devices. I'm trying to figure out the event driven reader scheme where on received data, the original source example is using a `HexDump` method on the byte array.

```
 private void updateReceivedData(byte[] data) {
        final String message = "Read " + data.length + " bytes: \n"
                + HexDump.dumpHexString(data) + "\n\n";
        mDumpTextView.append(message);
        mScrollView.smoothScrollTo(0, mDumpTextView.getBottom());
    }
```

Where is this class in the Android API? I can't figure it out. In the meantime I've copied the HexDump source from [here](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/base.git/+/master/core/java/com/android/internal/util/HexDump.java) and pasted it into my project as one of my classes. But, if this is already part of the Android API, then I shouldn't have to. I can't figure out what import its under.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe that class comes from Apache Commons, which is included in the project you reference [here](https://github.com/mik3y/usb-serial-for-android/blob/7b578918b0302882010cc6e3d25bae9bf55af461/usbSerialForAndroid/build.gradle#L25).

Comment: I think CommonsWare is correct r.e. the source of that particular implementation!

Answer (score 2):

> the original source example is using a HexDump method on the byte array... Where is this class in the Android API?

It's not in the Android SDK. It is [a class in the example project](https://github.com/mik3y/usb-serial-for-android/blob/v2.1.0/usbSerialExamples/src/main/java/com/hoho/android/usbserial/util/HexDump.java). As in your case, it is a clone of the one from the AOSP.